# ffmpeg extracts only part of 1 audio stream from .ts file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Here is what `ffprobe input.ts` shows:

```
  libavutil     56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
  libavcodec    58. 93.100 / 58. 93.100
  libavformat       58. 47.100 / 58. 47.100
  libavdevice       58. 11.100 / 58. 11.100
  libavfilter         7. 86.100 /  7. 86.100
  libswscale          5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample       3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc       55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'D:\Downloads\TEST\audio.ts':
  Duration: 02:22:29.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 51 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 83 kb/s
```

So the length of .ts file is 2h:22m:29.67s and looks like it contains *only audio* (AAC): when i open it in Windows Media Player i can jump to **any position within the 2h:22m range** and hear sound playing, and there is no video on the screen. This makes me think the extracted audio will also be of 2h:22m length, but i get only a **51m:14s** file. 
I tried the following commands:
1) `ffmpeg -i input.ts -vn -acodec copy outputaudio.aac`
2) `ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy outputaudio.aac` (as far as i understood this is "extract ALL audiotracks" command)
3) `ffmpeg -i input.ts -ss 00:00:00 -t 02:22:29.6 -q:a 0 -map a outputaudio.aac` (to **force** extraction to the full length, i.e. 2h:22m)
4) `ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:a outputaudio.aac -map 0:v outputonlyvideo.avi`  (i heard this is an alternative way to force extraction of *full-length* audio through simultaneous extraction of video. Though looks like my .ts has no video, i decided to try this command too and got an error message: **Stream map '0:v' matches no streams**)
What am i doing wrong? Which alternative commands can i try?
Is it possible, that the *real* length of audio stream is 51m:14s only? But why i can listen to all 2h:22m length in Windows Media Player - could 51m:14s piece be somehow *looped* inside .ts to create an impression of 2h:22m length?

Comment: Raw AAC files have no timestamps so any silence generated by timestamp gaps in the TS file will be lost. What's the use for the raw AAC file?

Comment: @Gyan I don't care in fact what the final format will be - for example **mp3** will be fine for me. So do you mean that extraction of audio in **.aac** format stops at 51m:14s because silence of _significant length_ starts in .ts at that time? What can i do to avoid this behavior and extract **all** 2h:22m of audio?

Comment: Say you're recording a teleconference. One of the participants speaks for the first minute, goes on mute for a minute, then starts speaking again. There will be audio data for the first minute and then audio data for the third minute. There are no 'silent' audio packets for the 2nd minute. The minute's gap is generated using timestamps. When this stream is extracted to a format without timestamps, the 3rd minute's data will play immediately after the 1st minute and so duration is "lost" but no actual audio. Depending on how you intend to use the extract, there are various ways to proceed.

Comment: @Gyan Got it, thank you! The idea is to combine (merge) ripped .mp3 audio with the related video. For this reason all pieces of silence in the output .mp3 should be 100% aligned (in terms of **timing**) with those in the original .ts file - as smth. happens in video (of course) during periods of silence - none of movies have an audiotrack _without_ periods of silence. P.S. Yes, i know i can use ffmpeg to merge audio/video _without_ initially ripping .mp3 stream from .ts, but i still want to know how to avoid this "silence cut" - as you say it's somehow possible.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve duration by plugging in timestamp gaps with silence, use the aresample filter.

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:a -af aresample=async=1 -ss 00:00:00 -t 02:22:29.6 -q:a 0 output.aac
```